# How can I a field as required based on selection of radio button in a form

Tags: jquery

There is a custom radio button. On select of 'yes' of that button another field is there which should not be required

```js
$("#btnFormSubmit").click(function() {
  var radioValue = $("input[name='CustomDuration']:checked").val();
  if (radioValue == 'Yes') {
    $("#frmCertificateRequirement").validate({
      rules: {
        ValidDurationMonths: {
          required: false
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please tag your questions appropriately. This has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to call `validate()` when the page loads, not when the submit button of the form is clicked.

With regards to your issue, the [`required`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/) property will accept a selector you can use to dynamically set the validation requirements for the element. Try this:

```js
$("#frmCertificateRequirement").validate({
  rules: {
    ValidDurationMonths: {
      required: 'input[name="CustomDuration"]:checked'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to show the Required Message when the radio button is checked . 
Then There is no closing of your code , please correct it.

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="btnFormSubmit" id="btnFormSubmit" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username/Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnFormSubmit">submit</button>
</form>
<input type="checkbox" name="CustomDuration" id="CustomDuration" value="Yes">checkbox

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**JQUERY Code with perfect closing**

```
$("#btnFormSubmit").click(function () {
   var radioValue = $('input[name="CustomDuration"]:checked').val();

   if (radioValue == "Yes") {
      $("#login_form").validate({
         rules:{
            username: 
            {
                required: false,
            }
         },
      });
    }
 }); /*You have missing this closing*/
```

Comment: Your Suggestion is Not Working

Comment: @Divide i have check code working . Now i have added HTML code .Please implement it.

Comment: ReferenceError: required is not defined
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ ReferenceError()
message: ""
name: "ReferenceError"
toString: ƒ toString()
__proto__: Object